# What does Minato's teleportation kunai say?

Tags: naruto, japanese-language

So I've been wondering what Minato's teleportation kunai said, but I have found nothing. I can only recognize the first and second characters. The first one means Shinobi, and the second one means love. I can't understand the last two.

So my question is if anyone knows what Minato's kunai say.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

忍愛之剣 (にんあいのけん 又は しのびあいのけん)

Sword of Shinobi's Love

That image is not accurate. The person who drew the picture clearly didn't pay much attention to the characters.

There is a YouTube video called "Did Naruto lose his six path sage mode" The cover photo has these four characters

Also, if you google these 4 characters, you will see there were a lot of people that have asked this question before

Comment: Well I looked more into what 忍愛之剣 meant in Japanese and I got "Sword Noriyuki ShinobuAi" which I think means what you said. I decided to look further into it and in Traditional Chinese it means "Ninja Love Sword", which is similar to what you said but not really the same if you think about it.

Answer (score 3):

It does says **忍愛之剣** *(nin-ai-no-ken)*. It appears in manga 673 and in anime episode 424. Not quite sure what it mean, and why the talisman changed.

[image]

Comment: Pronounced _nin'ai no ken_, probably. Good of you to muster some evidence for this!

Answer (score 2):

Ninkaku Fuzetsu (忍覚符絶, Literally meaning: Endurance Awakening Talisman Absolute). I don't know, maybe that just his signature and didn't have anything to do with Hiraishin because Tobirama's seal is in different shape and they have same purpose.

Comment: I should point out that the sequence of characters "忍覚符絶" does not appear anywhere in a google search besides on the Naruto wikia, and hence strikes me as of dubious veracity. "符絶", in particular is not a sequence of characters I would expect to see ever.